# Вылетает приложение при нажатии на уведомление

Tags: android

Есть активити, в котором из первого получаем ссылку на аудиопоток и проигрываем его через ExoPlayer. Также в этом активити строится уведомление, куда выводятся информация о текущем потоке и кнопка "Стоп". При нажатии на уведомление открывается данное активити.

Иногда (не во всех случаях) при нажатии на уведомление приложение вылетает. В маркете набралось около 2000 сбоев и все идут с одной ошибкой практически. Как я понимаю переменная stream оказывается пустой в момент когда нажимаю на уведомление. Как исправить этот момент, может я в коде ошибку допустил? Вот сам код плеера

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private String stream;
    private String radio;
    private int img;
    private boolean isPlay;
    private String MAYBE_ACTION = "MAYBE_ACTION";

    private ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private TextView txtRadio;
    private CircleImageView imgRadio;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    TrackSelector trackSelector;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;

    BroadcastReceiver br;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);
        imgRadio = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRadio);

        //Получаем текст из списка и ссылку на радио
        stream = getIntent().getExtras().getString("stream").toString().trim();
        radio = getIntent().getExtras().getString("radio").toString().trim();
        img = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("img");

        imgRadio.setImageResource(img);

        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory streamSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(streamSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl());
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        //Set media controller
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        // Bind the player to the view.
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(stream);
        // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
        // Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        isPlay = true;

        if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
            btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
        }

        /*Блок для создания уведомлений*/
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Намерение для запуска второй активности
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
        intent.putExtra("stream", stream);
        intent.putExtra("radio", radio);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        //Намерение для закрытия активности, если нажали кнопку Стоп
        Intent closeIntent = new Intent();
        closeIntent.setAction(MAYBE_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Строим уведомление
        Notification builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setTicker(radio)
                .setContentTitle("Играет: " + radio)
                /*.setContentText("Это я, почтальон Печкин. Принес для вас посылку")*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pendingIntent)
                .build();


        //Настойчивое уведомление
        builder.flags = builder.flags | Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder);
        /*Блок для создания уведомлений*/

        /*BroadcastReceiver*/
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            // действия при получении сообщений
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                finish();
            }
        };
        // создаем фильтр для BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);
        // регистрируем (включаем) BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
        /*BroadcastReceiver*/

        txtRadio.setText(radio);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifManager.cancelAll();
        super.onDestroy();
        player.release();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }

    public void onPlayPause(View view) {
        if (isPlay == true) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                isPlay = false;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            }
        } else if (isPlay == false) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == false) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                isPlay = true;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А это ошибка

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2439)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2499)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1360)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5487)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:765)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:655)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at ru.ars.radio.Player.onCreate (Player.java:134)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6556)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2392)
```

Стока 134 - это

```
stream = getIntent().getExtras().getString("stream").toString().trim();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильнее переписать этот кусок кода? И почему выбрасывается такое исключение

Comment: Почитайте про [флаги в PendingIntent](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/204-urok-119-pendingintent-flagi-requestcode-alarmmanager.html). Краш, потому что при старте активити в `onCreate` пустые `extras` из за некорректного флага `0` при установки `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю инфо по вашей ссылке